# Aiogram сообщения

Tags: telegram, бот, aiogram

Как отправить сообщение пользователю по `chat_id`, если он уже писал боту (сообщения разрешены).

```
async def log():
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=111111, text="Программа запущена")
```

Такой вариант не работает, возможно из-за отсутствия хендлера сообщений. Нужно как-то вызвать функцию `log()`, но я не знаю как.

Comment: Ну и какая ошибка? Гадать будем? И зачем Вам для отправки сообщения отдельная функция?

Comment: Уже решил проблему, использовал asincio. А сама программа не связана с телеграмом, функция вызывается по мере прохождения программы и логирует действия.